# Manage maven project version by profiles not by parent

Tags: maven

I have a parent tag in pom.xml like this:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.de</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyApplication</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.7-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

Also I have different profiles:

```
        <profiles>
            <profile>
                <id>default-environment-settings</id>
                <properties>
                    <app.env>dev</app.env>
                </properties>
                <activation>
                    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
                </activation>
            </profile>
                <profile>
                <id>xyz</id>
                <properties>
                    <app.env>profile2</app.env>
                </properties>
                <activation>
                    <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
                </activation>
            </profile>
        <profiles>
```

Now I want that my application's version is managed by profiles not as a global parent so that each profile can have it's private version number.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this ?

```
            <profiles>
                <profile>
                    <id>default-environment-settings</id>
                    <properties>
                        <app.env>dev</app.env>
                        <projectVersion>1.0-SNAPSHOT</projectVersion>
                    </properties>
                    <activation>
                        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
                    </activation>
                </profile>
                    <profile>
                    <id>xyz</id>
                    <properties>
                        <app.env>profile2</app.env>
                        <projectVersion>1.0</projectVersion>
                    </properties>
                    <activation>
                        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
                    </activation>
                </profile>
            <profiles>
```

And don't forget to put on your artifact

```
<version>${projectVersion}</version>
```

Comment: It somehow works but the problem comes when I run the Jenkins build job to deploy the maven site. The build works locally but not on my remote server. It shown the error: _[INFO] Installing c:\jenkins\workspace\my-application\pom.xml to C:\.m2\repository\my-application\${projectVersion}\application-${projectVersion}.pom
[INFO] --- maven-site-plugin:3.4:site (default-cli) @ application ---
[WARNING] Report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin has an empty version.
_ So the version number is not recognizable to maven site.

Comment: Ultimately it prints the error: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.4:site (default-cli) on project portal: failed to get report for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin: The parameters 'version' for goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.9:dependency-info are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]

Comment: Can you update your question with the full related pom ?
Also what command does your Jenkins job ?

Comment: pom.xml is actually quite complex as I have multiple subprojects. Jenkins job uses this command "clean install site:site site:deploy" This problem is not only in Jenkins but is reproduce able locally as well. Can you tell me is there any configuration to generate maven site? where can I find this?

Answer (score 0):

Profiles are not intended to declare POM's versions. If you define profiles as mentioned in [eclideria's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37992290/1744774) and your parent's POM with:

```
  <groupId>com.de</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyApplication</artifactId>
  <version>${projectVersion}</version>
```

it will result in:

```
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.de:MyApplication:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'version' contains an expression but should be a constant. @ com.de:MyApplication:${projectVersion}, ...MyApplication directory.../pom.xml, line ..., column ...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
```